# Remove blanks from combobox in excel vba but keep indexes

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

So I am pulling data from a data base to populate a combobox. Each value as an ID associated with it and I am using that ID as the index in the combobox for the value. So if the ID is 2 I am putting it in index 2. The first problem is that if I don't populate the box with something, I'm using blanks, it won't let me use the index. So if I haven't populated at least 10 blanks I can't stick the value with an ID of 10 at index 10. The other problem is that there are gaps. So if I am putting in values with indexes 2,3,5,7,8,10 there are blanks at 0,1,4,6,9. Is there a way to get rid of the blanks but keep the indexes? Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks.

this is how I am putting the values into the combobox. I'm using DEPOT_ID as the index.

```
ComboBox1.AddItem rs![DEPOT_NAME], rs![DEPOT_ID]
```

Comment: You might want to read what you've written again, and try to do so from the point of view of readers who have *absolutely no information* about what you're trying to do. If you were one of us, and knew **nothing** about the project in the question, would you be able to figure out what's being asked here? I certainly can't.

Comment: I don't think its possible to have an index with gaps. You will need to have an array or something behind the scenes to map your indexes with that of the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use an interim structure to work as a map or a dictionary.

Create an array in VBA and then as you assign items to your combobox record the true index with the combobox index.  Then when it is selected you can pull the index out of the array.

Its been a long time since I wrote vba so this is probably horrible.

eg.

```
Dim ComboBoxIndexs(100) As Integer 
Dim ArrayIndex as Integer
Dim SelectedIndex as Integer
Dim SelectedDepotID as Integer

'for each combo box item (I can't remember loops in vba)
'allocating to each item
ComboBox1.AddItem rs![DEPOT_NAME], rs![DEPOT_ID]

ComboBoxIndexs(ArrayIndex) = rs![DEPOT_ID]
ArrayIndex = ArrayIndex +1;

'end of for loop.

'When you select an item and want to read it.


 SelectedIndex = Combobox1.Value

 'now get your depot id from array
 SelectedDepotID = ComboBoxIndexs(SelectedIndex)
```